# Python: Transformation of data obtained from STEAM API via request.get to a format that can be uploaded to the database

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying get data from Steam API via request.get and then save it as a .csv file

Using the following code where `Cookie` is a `steamLogin` key to my session id

```
import requests

cookie = {'XXX'}    

data = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=PL&currency=6&appid=730&market_hash_name=Operation%20Breakout%20Weapon%20Case', cookies=cookie)

print(data.text)
```

Then I receive following response:

```
{"success":true,"price_prefix":"","price_suffix":"zł","prices":[["Jul 02 2014 01: +0",18.845,"70167"],["Jul 03 2014 01: +0",14.695,"44849"],["Jul 04 2014 01: +0",17.302,"25137"],["Jul 05 2014 01: +0",17.527,"18923"],["Jul 06 2014 01: +0",17.782,"15788"],["Jul 07 2014 01: +0",18.857,"12800"],["Jul 08 2014 01: +0",19.649,"10284"],["Jul 09 2014 01: +0",13.178,"25336"],["Jul 10 2014 01: +0",8.709,"35829"],["Jul 11 2014 01: +0",7.304,"35745"],["Jul 12 2014 01: +0",7.924,"26017"],["Jul 13 2014 01: +0",8.274,"20141"],["Jul 14 2014 01: +0",8.676,"17805"],["Jul 15 2014 01: +0",8.745,"17473"],["Jul 16 2014 01: +0",7.837,"21039"],["Jul 17 2014 01: +0",5.683,"26759"],["Jul 18 2014 01: +0",5.576,"26195"],["Jul 19 2014 01: +0",5.907,"23912"],["Jul 20 2014 01: +0",5.975,"21608"],["Jul 21 2014 01: +0",6.024,"20291"],["Jul 22 2014 01: +0",6.319,"19155"],["Jul 23 2014 01: +0",6.406,"20724"],["Jul 24 2014 01: +0",5.381,"26551"],["Jul 25 2014 01: +0",5.362,"33527"],["Jul 26 2014 01: +0",5.875,"29971"],["Jul 27 2014 01: +0",5.754,"27428"],["Jul 28 2014 01: +0",5.793,"27553"],["Jul 29 2014 01: +0",6.31,"25911"],["Jul 30 2014 01: +0",6.305,"20992"],["Jul 31 2014 01: +0",5.931,"25829"],["Aug 01 2014 01: +0",5.939,"29718"],["Aug 02 2014 01: +0",6.031,"27092"],["Aug 03 2014 01: +0",5.935,"27522"],["Aug 04 2014 01: +0",5.865,"26015"],["Aug 05 2014 01: +0",5.582,"26988"],["Aug 06 2014 01: +0",5.737,"26375"],["Aug 07 2014 01: +0",5.685,"26571"],["Aug 08 2014 01: +0",5.607,"27936"],["Aug 09 2014 01: +0",5.546,"27268"],["Aug 10 2014 01: +0",5.403,"27117"],["Aug 11 2014 01: +0",5.343,"28408"],["Aug 12 2014 01: +0",5.356,"26045"],["Aug 13 2014 01: +0",5.341,"25808"],["Aug 14 2014 01: +0",5.301,"27180"],["Aug 15 2014 01: +0",5.405,"31669"],["Aug 16 2014 01: +0",5.368,"32656"] etc.
```

Can you first confirm what format this data is returned in?

I have tried many times to format this data using pandas dataframe to save the file as .csv with columns: ['date','price','quantity'] but it ended in failure..

```
df = pd.DataFrame(requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=PL&currency=6&appid=730&market_hash_name=Operation%20Breakout%20Weapon%20Case', cookies=cookie))
 
df.apply(pd.Series.explode, axis=1)
```

I tried many times but the data looks hopeless (there should be over 3500 records)

```
0     b'{"success":true,"price_prefix":"","price_suf...
1     b'695,"44849"],["Jul 04 2014 01: +0",17.302,"2...
2     b'"Jul 07 2014 01: +0",18.857,"12800"],["Jul 0...
3     b'1: +0",8.709,"35829"],["Jul 11 2014 01: +0",...
4     b'41"],["Jul 14 2014 01: +0",8.676,"17805"],["...
...                                                 ...
1093  b'74"],["Jan 21 2023 21: +0",18.882,"347"],["J...
1094  b'0: +0",18.872,"265"],["Jan 22 2023 01: +0",1...
1095  b',["Jan 22 2023 04: +0",19.051,"207"],["Jan 2...
1096  b'0",19.151,"191"],["Jan 22 2023 08: +0",19.16...
1097  b'an 22 2023 11: +0",18.882,"342"],["Jan 22 20...

[1098 rows x 1 columns]
```

Do you have any ideas on how can I remove the unnecessary information that is at the beginning of the response and then separate the data that is in square brackets as separate columns and rows?

Answer (score 0):

This is a json file.
First extract the data you need and then put the extracted data into a dataframe.

To extract the data you can use this for example:

```
data_json=data.json
prices_list=data_json["prices"]
for price in prices_list:
    print(price)
```